# MSSQL: Create column based on row when using count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

How to create columns based on columns.

so for row "EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 3 - Operator", it would create a column called "operator" and the value would be the value from "option press"

In this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ec284/16)

the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IVRInterval
    ([cLevelName] varchar(50), [nLevel] FLOAT(20), [I3TimeStampGMT] DATETIME, [cExitPath] varchar(20))
;
INSERT INTO IVRInterval
    ([cLevelName], [nLevel], [I3TimeStampGMT], [cExitPath])
VALUES
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 3 - Operator', '5', '2017-10-05 09:30:00.000', 'Workgroup Queue'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 3 - Operator', '5', '2017-10-05 10:00:00.000', 'Workgroup Queue'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 3 - Operator', '5', '2017-10-11 11:30:00.000', 'Workgroup Queue'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 3 - Operator', '5', '2017-10-11 12:30:00.000', 'Workgroup Queue'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 1 - SD', '5', '2017-10-11 13:30:00.000', 'Workgroup Queue'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 1 - SD', '5', '2017-10-09 08:30:00.000', 'Workgroup Queue'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 1 - SD', '5', '2017-10-09 11:00:00.000', '*'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 1 - SD', '5', '2017-10-11 15:00:00.000', 'Workgroup Queue'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 1 - SD', '5', '2017-10-06 09:30:00.000', 'Workgroup Queue'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 1 - SD', '5', '2017-10-06 11:30:00.000', 'Workgroup Queue'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 1 - SD', '5', '2017-10-09 14:30:00.000', '*'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 2 - Lobby', '5', '2017-10-06 13:30:00.000', 'Workgroup Queue'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 2 - Lobby', '5', '2017-10-09 14:00:00.000', 'Workgroup Queue'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 2 - Lobby', '5', '2017-10-04 07:30:00.000', 'Workgroup Queue'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 2 - Lobby', '5', '2017-10-04 08:30:00.000', 'Workgroup Queue'),
    ('EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 2 - Lobby', '5', '2017-10-10 08:00:00.000', '*')
```

i run this query

```
select 

Convert(date,I3TimeStampGMT) as 'Dates',
(select cLevelName) as 'Options Name',
count(I3TimeStampGMT) as 'Option Press'

from IVRInterval

where
I3TimeStampGMT between '2017-10-04 00:00:00' and '2017-10-11 23:59:59'
and cLevelName like '%%EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN -%%'
and nLevel = '5'
and not cExitPath = '*'

group by cLevelName, Convert(date,I3TimeStampGMT)
```

I get this result

```
Dates       Options Name                         Option Press
2017-10-04  EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 2 - Lobby      2
2017-10-05  EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 3 - Operator   2
2017-10-06  EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 1 - SD         2
2017-10-06  EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 2 - Lobby      1
2017-10-09  EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 1 - SD         1
2017-10-09  EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 2 - Lobby      1
2017-10-11  EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 1 - SD         2
2017-10-11  EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 3 - Operator   2
```

I would like to have my result like this

```
Date       Lobby    SD    Operator
2017-10-11  0       1       1
```

I got read-only on the mssql

Comment: as well as linking to the fiddle, copy the fiddle code to the question and please add some description of the output to the post, I can't see how that result could lead to your desired output.

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CAST([I3TimeStampGMT]  AS DATE) AS [date],
     COUNT(CASE WHEN [cLevelName] LIKE '%Lobby' THEN 1 END)    AS Lobby,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN [cLevelName] LIKE '%SD' THEN 1 END)       AS SD,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN [cLevelName] LIKE '%Operator' THEN 1 END) AS Operator
FROM IVRInterval
GROUP BY CAST([I3TimeStampGMT]  AS DATE);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/BRD79108)**

Comment: thank you but i get Error(s), warning(s):
Incorrect syntax near 'COUNT'. when i run it on rextester

Comment: @Louis-PhilippeDescamps Missing comma after `AS [date]`. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

We need to use the '%%' expression, which is meaningful everywhere when using like in the name column. Because if there is a gap at the end of the word,  it will misinterpret the desired word and give wrong result when grouping.

```
create table stack(Dates date,name nvarchar(100))

insert into stack values

('2017-10-04', 'EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 2 - Lobby  ') ,
('2017-10-05', 'EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 3 - Operator') ,
('2017-10-06', 'EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 1 - SD') ,
('2017-10-06', 'EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 2 - Lobby') ,
('2017-10-09', 'EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 1 - SD') ,
('2017-10-09', 'EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 2 - Lobby') ,
('2017-10-11', 'EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 1 - SD') ,
('2017-10-11', 'EOIVR - SB_Internal_LN - 3 - Operator')

SELECT Dates as Date,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN name LIKE '%Lobby%' THEN 1 END)    AS Lobby,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN name LIKE '%SD%' THEN 1 END)       AS SD,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN name LIKE '%Operator%' THEN 1 END) AS Operator
FROM stack
GROUP BY Dates
```